# ArcObjects 10.3 Page Layout

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3

We are upgrading ArcGIS from version 10.0 to 10.3 and need to update our server object extensions.

Esri state that when upgrading:

"Avoid using ArcObjects from the Carto library that are specifically designed for use with MXDs. This includes IMap, ILayer, and items related to data frames and page layouts.

In 10.0, we developed an SOE that could dynamically generate map images (with legends, scale bar etc.) using the PageLayout class from ArcObjects Java API. But as the above statement suggests, apparently we can't use that PageLayout class anymore. We need fine control of the page layout and so what is the alternative in 10.3? Sample Page Layout SOEs provided use the PageLayout class. So can we still use this class in our SOEs when upgrading to 10.3 or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Server classes instead of Desktop classes for mapping purposes. For example instead of using IMap, use IMapServer which is designed to work with MapServices. In the next sentence it says:

> Instead, SOEs should use ArcObjects designed for working with map
> services, such as MapServer, ImageServer and related classes.

As there is not an equivalent class for PageLayout in Server Classes (like IMapServer),
to work with pagelayouts, you may write a SOE ([PageLayout REST Server Object Extension With Version 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualHelp/engine/index.html#//0001000003t4000000)). For newer version (after 10) use [Export Web Map](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00540000001m000000) to generate a raster from PageLayout.

> This tool is shipped with ArcGIS Server to support web services for
> printing, including the preconfigured service named PrintingTools

Comment: We did develop and use an an SOE using PageLayout class in 10.0.  We are now upgrading to 10.3 where Esri have said in their statement that page layout related items can no longer be used in SOEs.  The sample PageLayout SOE you have linked to is for 10.0 and uses the PageLayout class.  So, back to my original question, what is the alternative i.e. which ArcObjects classes in 10.3 do we now use in our SOE to generate maps images with legends etc if we are no longer allowed to use the PageLayout class? Thanks.

Comment: PageLayout Control is part of Web ADF API and ADF is deprecated after 10. With newer Version you should use Export Web Map Server Tool. I added a link in my original post